# Server program using Get and Post

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

My index.html page

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="./login.html">Please Login Here!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My login.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example of Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.html" method="post">
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My server page

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/static/index.html');
})

app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/static/"+"login.html");
})

app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    res.send(`Username : ${username} Password: ${password}`)
})

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`This app is listening on port : ${port}`));
```

I am new to node.js.When I run using node server.js, I get Cannot GET /login.html.I can get into index.html. Why I am getting this.
This is my directory

```
. ├── package.json
. ├── server.js
. └── static
. . ├── index.html
. . └── login.html
```

Answer (score 0):

try using **express.static()** middleware.

you can read more about serving static files [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

**ex:**

```
const express = require('express');
const path=require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')));//use folder containing your html files

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile('static/index.html');
})

app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile("static/login.html");
})

app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    res.send(`Username : ${username} Password: ${password}`)
})

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`This app is listening on port : ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your request is to

`/login.html`

but there is no such route set up in your server.

There is a route

`/login`

which sends the file `login.html`, so, to hit that route, it would be a url that looks like:

`http://localhost:3000/login`

NOT

`http://localhost:3000/login.html`

Alternatively, [set up `static` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve static files from a specified directory.